# How to use google drive image inside css background-image: url() function?

Tags: html, css, image, url, google-drive-api

I have an image on google drive and I would like to use that inside my html code.
[Image on Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXGs4wvPdiz1JHoEuSkMMLbjaRN0od5a/view) 
I give this url inside `css background-image: url()` but which is not loading the image.How can i fix this?.I'm added my snippet below.

```css
#image-container{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  background-image:url(https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXGs4wvPdiz1JHoEuSkMMLbjaRN0od5a/view);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:100% 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div id="image-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use file ID, how about this?

> http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1BXGs4wvPdiz1JHoEuSkMMLbjaRN0od5a

#### Note :

- If the image is not shared, the link gets to be not able to be used.

Comment: @Dream Hunter Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong URL, use this (Right click on image and copy image url):

```
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/Rm_CMMHU3iCC1tEeBpglpNIy5W3y1kwjSBDvGrcgoUBZz6Mv3NJc94pqQbiR1vVszp2gAdw-D0xBjHLkUygD=w1920-h974-rw
```

Also, it is better just to download the image and place it in a folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly put images using the share link in the css.
Do the following steps to get a viewable link of your image.

1. Upload your image to google drive.
2. Share your image from the sharing option and Copy your sharing link.
   [image]
3. If your link is https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wtKp3Kpl0bLeaEhajgkXHAcpcS9qnoO9/view?usp=sharing then copy the id (in this case 1wtKp3Kpl0bLeaEhajgkXHAcpcS9qnoO9) and append it with the following url

   ```
   http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<your_id>
   ```

   For example:

   ```
   http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1wtKp3Kpl0bLeaEhajgkXHAcpcS9qnoO9
   ```
4. Paste the URL inside the url() method in the css file.

   ```
   #image-container{
       background-image: url('https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BXGs4wvPdiz1JHoEuSkMMLbjaRN0od5a/view');
       ...
   }
   ```